# Need help with xPath expressions with namespaces

Tags: java, spring, xpath, expression

I need some help with a xpath expression.

I have the following xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns="http://schemas.test.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
    <nodeA>text</nodeA>
    <nodeB>
        <nodeb1>
            <nodeb1a>
                <nodeTest>hello</nodeTest>
            </nodeb1a>
        </nodeb1>
    </nodeB>
</Response>
```

I am using Springs rest template to retrieve the data.

Here is where I am using a xpath expression to get the node values:

```
xpathTemplate.evaluate("base:*", xmlSource, new NodeMapper() {
        public Object mapNode(Node node, int i) throws DOMException {
            Element response = (Element) node;
            System.out.println("hi: " + response.getTextContent());
```

I added base to my namespace map like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> nameSpaces = new HashMap<String, String>();
nameSpaces.put("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
nameSpaces.put("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
nameSpaces.put("base", "http://schemas.test.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");
((Jaxp13XPathTemplate) xpathTemplate).setNamespaces(nameSpaces);
```

Using the expression base:* gives me the Response node and I am able to drill down to the child nodes using .getChildNodes and creating nodelists for each child.

I would like to get the hello value directly with the xpath expression but I am not able to get it to work with anything but base:*.  Can someone help me with my expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This XPath expression:

```
/base:Response/base:nodeB/base:nodeb1/base:nodeb1a/base:nodeTest
```

Assuming `base` is bound to `http://schemas.test.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1` namespace URI.

Comment: Awesome!  That works.  Thank you.  Quick question so I understand it better.  Why do I need base: for each node level?  I did try it both ways and it doesn't work without it.  Just unsure since it is only used in the main Response node.

Comment: @Blong824: You are welcome. You need `base:` prefix for each name test because all those elements belongs to such namespace URI.

Answer (score 2):

`hello = xpathTemplate.evaluateAsString("//*[local-name()='nodeTest']", source);`

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following:

```
xpathTemplate.evaluate("/Response/nodeB/nodeb1/nodeb1a/nodeTest", ...
```

If you need more information on XPath, you can try the following 
http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

My website also proposes a tool to test your xpath queries: 
http://ap2cu.com/tools/xpath/index.php5

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I could not get that to work.  Even when I try /Response I do not get any results.  base:* is the only expression I can get to work.  I think it has to do with the namespaces but I am not sure.  Any other ideas?